# .net core email verification link on GET fails to cast object of type 'System.GUID' to object of type 'Sytem.String'

Tags: url, casting, asp.net-identity, url-parameters

I've been working with .net core to send out a user verification link through email. The link builds just fine and it looks to be alright, but when I click the link I get a `System.InvalidCastException` that breaks the page. The link takes you to a razor page and is built like this:

```
var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
var codeBytes = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
var callbackUrl = Url.Page(      // the UrlHelperExtensions.Page method
    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
    pageHandler: null,
    values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = codeBytes, returnUrl = svm.Input.ReturnUrl },
    protocol: Request.Scheme);                        

string htmlLink = HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl);
```

where the `htmlLink` is the link that I should be able to click on to verify the email address. I then send the email using an `SmtpClient` like this:

```
public bool SendEmailMessage(string subjectHeader, string emailBody, string userEmail)
{

    MailMessage msg = CreateMailMessage(subjectHeader, emailBody, userEmail);

    // call this function to create the client and send the email
    return SendEmail(msg);
}

private MailMessage CreateMailMessage(string subject, string body, string email)
{
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage
    {
        IsBodyHtml = true,
        From = new MailAddress(_ADMIN_ADDRESS, _FROM_NAME),
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body
    };

    msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));

    return msg;
}

private bool SendEmail(MailMessage message)
{
    using (var client = new SmtpClient(_SMTP_HOST, _PORT))
    {
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(_SMTP_USER, _SMTP_PASSWORD);
        client.EnableSsl = true;

        try
        {
            client.Send(message);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Email not sent");
            Console.WriteLine($"Error message: {ex.Message}");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This sends the email without error, and the Razor Page handles the OnGet method like so:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string userId, string code)
{
    if (userId == null || code == null)
    {
        return RedirectToPage("/Index");
    }

    UserId = userId;
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{userId}'.");
    }

    code = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(code));
    var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);

    StatusMessage = result.Succeeded ? "Thank you for confirming your email." : "Error confirming your email.";
    IsSuccess = result.Succeeded;
    return Page();
}
```

I've been looking through the stack trace (see below) but it looks like all the modules used are things that I work with only indirectly. I haven't been able to find yet why I get an `InvalidCastException`, but is there some bit of code that I'm missing? My Startup.cs file includes `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` but I don't think this has to do with the casting error.

Any thoughts?

```
Aug 10 21:42:13 ip-172-31-36-195 web: #033[41m#033[30mfail#033[39m#033[22m#033[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
Aug 10 21:42:13 ip-172-31-36-195 web: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Aug 10 21:42:13 ip-172-31-36-195 web: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.String'.
Aug 10 21:42:13 ip-172-31-36-195 web: at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.PropertyHelper.CallPropertySetter[TDeclaringType,TValue](Action`2 setter, Object target, Object value)
Aug 10 21:42:13 ip-172-31-36-195 web: at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetValue(Object instance, Object value)
Aug 10 21:42:13 ip-172-31-36-195 web: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.SaveTempDataPropertyFilterBase.SetPropertyValues(ITempDataDictionary tempData)
Aug 10 21:42:13 ip-172-31-36-195 web: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.PageSaveTempDataPropertyFilter.OnPageHandlerExecuting(PageHandlerExecutingContext context)
Aug 10 21:42:13 ip-172-31-36-195 web: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
Aug 10 21:42:13 ip-172-31-36-195 web: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()
Aug 10 21:42:13 ip-172-31-36-195 web: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
Aug 10 21:42:13 ip-172-31-36-195 web: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
Aug 10 21:42:13 ip-172-31-36-195 web: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Aug 10 21:42:13 ip-172-31-36-195 web: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
Aug 10 21:42:13 ip-172-31-36-195 web: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Aug 10 21:42:13 ip-172-31-36-195 web: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
Aug 10 21:42:13 ip-172-31-36-195 web: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compared with a previous version that had been working, and I changed the following:

In my Startup.cs file I removed these lines:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json",
        optional: false,
        reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();
```

In my ConfirmEmail.cshtml.cs I removed the these lines:

```
[TempData]
public string UserId { get; set; }

// in OnGetAsync:
UserId = userId; // "userId" was passed in a URL parameter
```

Consequentially, n ConfirmEmail.cshtml I removed this line:

```
<a asp-controller="Transactions" asp-action="ResendVerificationlink" asp-route-userId="@Model.UserId">Resend Verification Link</a>
```

since the model no longer had the attribute `UserId`.

I'm not sure which of these changes caused the error to resolve, but I'd imagine it was the `UserId` in the `ConfirmEmail` class and razor page. Hopefully this is helpful if anyone else comes across the same error, I'm still very confused on what exactly went wrong and why the server was trying to cast a `System.GUID` to a `System.String`.